# Python: Grabbing an entire string as one element

Tags: python

my input looks like this:

```
 MSG1          .STRINGZ   “This is my sample string : "
 MEMORYSPACE   .BLKW      9
 NEWLINE       .FILL      #10
 NEG48         .FILl      #-48

      .END
```

right now i have a code that splits each line in my input file by word like such:

```
['MSG1', '.STRINGZ', '"This', 'is', 'a' , 'sample' , 'string','"']
['MEMORYSPACE', '.BLKW', '9']
['NEWLINE', '.FILL', '#10']
['NEG48', '.FILl', '#-48']
[]
['.END']
```

in the input file, on my first line where i have the string, i would like it to treat that whole string as one element so that i can count its length in my code. Is there any way of doing that? Here is my code:

```
f = open ('testLC31.txt', 'r')
line_count = 0

to_ignore = ["AND", "ADD", "LEA", "PUTS", "JSR", "LD", "JSRR" , "NOT", "LDI" ,
            "LDR", "ST", "STI", "STR", "BR" , "JMP", "TRAP" , "JMP", "RTI" ,
            "BR", "ST", "STI" , "STR" , "BRz", "BRn" , "HALT"]

label = []
instructions = []

for line in f:
    elem = line.split() if line.split() else ['']
    if len(elem) > 1 and elem[0] not in to_ignore:
        label.append(elem[0])
        instructions.append(elem[1])
        line_count += 1
    elif elem[0] in to_ignore:
        line_count += 1
```

Comment: Is the delimiter a tabulation, a run of spaces or some combination thereof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works by assuming that .STRINGZ is always on a line when signifying a string.

results in

"This is my sample string : "
len(strinz_): 32

```
text_ = """
MSG1          .STRINGZ   "This is my sample string : "
MEMORYSPACE   .BLKW      9
NEWLINE       .FILL      #10
NEG48         .FILl      #-48

      .END
"""

STRINGZ_ = '.STRINGZ'
line_count_ = 0

lines_ = text_.split('\n')

to_ignore = ["AND", "ADD", "LEA", "PUTS", "JSR", "LD", "JSRR" , "NOT", "LDI" ,
            "LDR", "ST", "STI", "STR", "BR" , "JMP", "TRAP" , "JMP", "RTI" ,
            "BR", "ST", "STI" , "STR" , "BRz", "BRn" , "HALT"]

label = []
instructions = []

for line in lines_:
    if STRINGZ_ in line:
        stringz_ = line.split(STRINGZ_)[1]
        print stringz_
        print 'len(stringz_): ' + str(len(stringz_))
    elem = line.split() if line.split() else ['']
    if len(elem) > 1 and elem[0] not in to_ignore:
        label.append(elem[0])
        instructions.append(elem[1])
        line_count_ += 1
    elif elem[0] in to_ignore:
        line_count_ += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

[`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method has an optional argument `maxsplit`, which limits the number of elements in the resulting list:

```
>>> 'MSG1          .STRINGZ   “This is my sample string : "'.split(None, 2)
['MSG1', '.STRINGZ', '“This is my sample string : "']
```

If you want something more complex than getting the first two words and leaving the rest intact, [`shlex.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html) may suit you. It uses shell-like syntax for splitting parts of the string and thus treats a string in quotes as a single element. You can setup the format exactly by creating a `shlex` object instance and changing its attributes. See documentation for details.

```
>>> shlex.split('MSG1          .STRINGZ   "This is my sample string : "')
['MSG1', '.STRINGZ', 'This is my sample string : ']
>>> shlex.split('MSG1          .STRINGZ   "This is my sample string : "', posix=False)
['MSG1', '.STRINGZ', '"This is my sample string : "']
```

If that is not enough as well, the option left is to write a full-fledged parser for your format, for example using [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) library.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this crude method of joining those strings back manually like so:

```
tags = ['MSG1', '.STRINGZ', '"This', 'is', 'a' , 'sample' , 'string','"']
FirstOccurance = 0
longtag = ""
for tag in tags:
    if FirstOccurance == 1:
        if tag == "\"":
            longtag += tag
        else:
            longtag += " "+tag
    if ("\"" in tag)  and (FirstOccurance == 0):
        longtag += tag
        FirstOccurance = 1
    elif ("\"" in tag) and (FirstOccurance == 1):
        FirstOccurance = 0

print longtag
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("filename") as f:
    rd = f.readlines()
    print (rd[0].split("\n")[0].split())
```

Split `\n` and spaces. Print first elements of each list. `readlines()` will return a list, it's easier to manipulate it. Also `with open()` method is better.

Answer (score 0):

A simple assembler? Here is a rough pass using pyparsing:

```
code = """
 MSG1          .STRINGZ   "This is my sample string : "
 MEMORYSPACE   .BLKW      9
 NEWLINE       .FILL      #10
 NEG48         .FILL      #-48

      .END"""

from pyparsing import Word, alphas, alphanums, Regex, Combine, quotedString, Optional

identifier = Word(alphas, alphanums+'_')
command = Word('.', alphanums)

integer = Regex(r'[+-]?\d+')
byte_literal = Combine('#' + integer)
command_arg = quotedString | integer | byte_literal
codeline = Optional(identifier)("label") + command("instruction") + Optional(command_arg("arg"))

for line in code.splitlines():
    line = line.strip()
    if not line:
        continue

    print line
    assemline = codeline.parseString(line)
    print assemline.dump()
    print
```

Prints

```
MSG1          .STRINGZ   "This is my sample string : "
['MSG1', '.STRINGZ', '"This is my sample string : "']
- arg: "This is my sample string : "
- instruction: .STRINGZ
- label: MSG1

MEMORYSPACE   .BLKW      9
['MEMORYSPACE', '.BLKW', '9']
- arg: 9
- instruction: .BLKW
- label: MEMORYSPACE

NEWLINE       .FILL      #10
['NEWLINE', '.FILL', '#10']
- arg: #10
- instruction: .FILL
- label: NEWLINE

NEG48         .FILL      #-48
['NEG48', '.FILL', '#-48']
- arg: #-48
- instruction: .FILL
- label: NEG48

.END
['.END']
- instruction: .END
```